# PrototypeJS - Cloning Input, Retains Checkboxes Even After removeAttribute in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I am cloning a row, changing some things in the element, then outputting the element to the page.  the problem is, when I remove the checked attributes, it works fine in IE, but FF retains the checked state from the original element that was cloned.

For example:

```
var newHTML = $$('.importRow')[0].clone(true);
$(newHTML).select('input').each(function(s, index) {  
   $(s).removeAttribute('checked'); //This is to remove any checked value
   if ($(s).hasClassName('someClass') && $(s).getValue() == 'someValue'){ //This is to assign a new default checked value
      $(s).setAttribute('checked','checked');
   }
}
$(this).up().insert({ 
   before: newHTML 
});
```

How would I get around this and make FF not retain the previously selected values?

EDIT:

Returning the element it shows it correctly, but Firefox remembers the value for some reason and I am not sure how to override this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the checkbox DOM attributes: `s.checked = false; s.defaultChecked = false;`, or alternatively, instead of removing the `checked` attribute, set its value to false: `s.writeAttribute('checked', 'false');`

Incidentally, once an element has been extended with the prototype functions, you don't need to repeatedly call `$()` on it; this just wastes CPU time.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck.  Even for text inputs, doing s.setAttribute('value','') doesn't work.  I have to do it after its added with Firefox.

Comment: Using DOM attributes works.  For inputs have to use s.value = "".